# ksoap2-android client throwing FileNotFoundException inside [KeepAlive]HttpsTransportSE.call()

Tags: android, sql-server-2005, ksoap2, soap-client, android-ksoap2

I am attempting to create an Android (2.2) SOAP client to connect to a SQL Server 2005 XML Web Services endpoint (and of course this requires authentication).  My SQL Server endpoint seems to be up and running (it's a simple function which takes a string (varchar(20)) and returns another string; the URL "https://10.1.1.20:444/dt2?wsdl" properly returns the WSDL XML. (I am not using the "?wsdl" part of the URL in my connection string; I just mention it to show the web service is working properly.)

All seems to be working well, until I am inside the call to KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE.call() (using ksoap2-android 2.5.4), and get to HttpTransportSE.class:150, where (ServiceConnection)connection.openInputStream() is called, which in turn calls connection.getInputStream() - that is what throws the FileNotFoundException.

Any idea what's happening here?  What is a good next debugging step?  Thanks for any input.

Comment: I am able to get a connection working to the sample code at http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx but I haven't been able to try any other SOAP endpoints with authentication or https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following question for more detail and the answer to the problem: [Getting ParsingError, InvalidSoapActionHeader on SQL Server SOAP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113144/getting-parsingerror-invalidsoapactionheader-on-sql-server-soap-request)